# Error in googleappscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run an app which script reads a spreadsheet and sends a email that is set in a column. But, I get the following error:
"It's not possible to convert email in (class). (line 6, file audit).
What is wrong? My code is that:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(2, 8).getValue(); //comeca na linha 2, da coluna H
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[8];  // First column //começa em 0. Logo, refere-se a coluna J
    var subject = "Você tem um prazo de auditoria vencendo em " + row[11] + " dias";
    var message = row[2]; 
    var expired = row[11]; 

    if (expired < 10); {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide Excel sheet data sample as well.

Comment: Column J is `row[9]` (Column H is `row[7]`). Also note that your `row` variable has only 8 values, since you obtain data as `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8);` So, your email address is `undefined`. **In the future, ensure you use the Apps Script debugger to thoroughly evaluate your code**

Comment: Roger, next time, a good way to find your mistake will be to use `Logger.log(emailAddress)` or `Logger.log(row[8])` before the error.

Comment: A    B     C     D     E     F      G       H

Answer (score 0):

I want get the email of the column "H". I changed my code following your tips. It is like this:

```
var startRow = 2; 
var numRows = sheet.getRange(2, 7).getValue(); 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7);
```

But the message is still showing:

> Can not convert Não to (class). (line 7, file "Code")

I need to get the email in column H and send a message. Not the column G.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with the following change:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 

var startRow = 1; 
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); 

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();
```